# How to extract two Paths from args in command-line Java?

Tags: java, command-line, parameter-passing, command-line-arguments, filepath

I'm making a Huffman Tree implementation that takes some data and prints the leaves of the tree, or serializes the tree into a file. The implementation uses a custom command line program that receives flags, a source path (`~/example/dir/source.txt`), and an output path (`~/example/dir/`). It would look like

```
mkhuffmantree -s -f ~/example/dir/source.txt ~/example/dir/
```

I'm not using a framework or library to pass the command line arguments, I want to do it manually. My solution has been:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
class mkhuffmantree
{ 
    boolean help = false;
    boolean interactive = false;
    boolean verbose = false;
    boolean serialize = false;
    boolean fromFile = false;
    File source;
    Path outputPath;

  public void readArgs(String[] args){
        for (String val:args) 
        if(val.contains(-h)){
            help = true;
        } else if(val.contains(-i)){
            interactive = true;
        } else if(val.contains(-v)){
            verbose = true;
        } else if(val.contains(-s)){
            serialize = true;
        } else if(val.contains(-f)){
            fromFile = true;
        }
    }

    public void main(String[] args){  
        if (args.length > 0){ 
            readArgs(args);            
        } 
    } 
}
```

But after interpreting the flags, I don't know how to store `~/example/dir/source.txt` in `File source`, and `~/example/dir/` in `Path outputPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have state as you are reading the values.

to start with, I suggest this command instead:

```
mkhuffmantree -s -f ~/example/dir/source.txt -o ~/example/dir/
```

Then when you hit -f, you set a new variable, let's say "nextParam" to SOURCE (Maybe an enum?  Could also be a final static int value like 1)  when you hit -o set "nextParam" to OUTPUT

Then BEFORE your switch but inside the loop (don't forget to add the braces you should have already put after your for statement!) you want something like:

```
if(nextParam == SOURCE) {
    fromFile = val;
    nextParam = NONE; // Reset so following params aren't sent to source
    continue;   // This is not a switch so it won't match anything else
}
```

repeat for OUTPUT

A different way to do it:

If  you don't want to use the -o, there is another approach that doesn't need the -f or -o, that is to put at the BOTTOM of the for loop a final "else" that puts the value into "source" unless source already has a value in which case you put it into outputFile.

If you do it this way, you can just get rid of -f altogether, it's meaningless since you are just saying that the two values that aren't matched as switches are assumed to be your files.

Comment: This was the most helpful answer, but I changed the implementation to recieve 3 and only 3 parameters, which consist of a single flag, and two paths. This way I could access the flag as `arg[0]`, and the paths as `arg[1..2]`, and verified the flags with `cases` and a `default` which displayed an error prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```java
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            String val = args[i];

            if (val.contains("-h")) {
                help = true;
            } else if (val.contains("-i")) {
                interactive = true;
            } else if (val.contains("-v")) {
                verbose = true;
            } else if (val.contains("-s")) {
                serialize = true;
            } else if (val.contains("-f")) {
                fromFile = true;
                source = new File(args[++i]);
            }
        }

        outputPath = Paths.get(args.length - 1);
```

Also, take a look into [Apache CLI](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/)